# ggplot scale x-axis in cubic square

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I wanna rescale the x-axis in a cubic square by defining a new function.

```
cuberoot_trans = function(){
 trans = function(x) x^(1/3)
 }

ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(x=carat, y=price)) + 
 geom_point(alpha=1.5, size=0.75, position = 'jitter') +
 scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 3), limits = c(0.2, 3), trans = cuberoot_trans())
```

> Error in paste0(x, "_trans") : 
>    cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check the documentation for `scales::trans_new` to see how to properly create new transformation scales

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out:)